# Issue with jQuery.InArray() returning -1

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am having an issue where `jQuery.InArray()` is returning -1 when I run a function, but I know that the values that I'm testing for are definitely in the array.

I know that they are in the array because if I console.log the values of the array right before I run `jQuery.inArray()` the values exist and display.  Here is an example of what I'm working with:

```
/* -- In page.php -- */
images = [8, 13, 21, 32, 40, 56]; 


/* -- In script.js -- */
console.log('images->', images); 
//output  images-> [8, 13, 21, 32, 40, 56]

var testingValue = 13;

console.log('inArray->', jQuery.inArray(testingValue, images)); //Should return 1
//output inArray-> -1

console.log('inArray->', jQuery.inArray(13, images)); //Should return 1
//output inArray-> -1

console.log('inArray->', jQuery.inArray("13", images)); //Should return -1
//output inArray-> -1

console.log('inArray->', jQuery.inArray('13', images)); //Should return -1 
//output inArray-> -1
```

All of these return `-1` even though the top two should return `1`.  The weird thing is that if I manually test for `jQuery.inArray(testingValue, images)` in the console, I do get the value 1.

**One thing to note:**  The variable `images` is created in the php page that the js file is included in.  This shouldn't be an issue.

**Additional note:** Yes, jQuery is included well before this part of the script runs.  Many other jQuery functions are running successfully before this one.

What I am wondering is if there are any gotchas to this function.  I have used it successfully in the past and can't see anything with my code which would prevent this from returning a proper value.

Comment: They seem to [work as intended](http://jsfiddle.net/rmEuS/1/)

Comment: I know it should work, it's just not working for some reason in my code.

Comment: Is there anything that would hold up the array declaration?  The weird thing is that I can do a console.log and definitely see that the function is defined with the values, only I'm not receiving the correct value.

Comment: It could be that somewhere in your code, `images` got overwritten or something. You cans set breakpoints and have a watch monitor that variable.

Comment: The PHP variable exists on the server, how is it recreated in the Javascript code?

Comment: @Guffa `images` was `console.log`-ged successfully so it must have printed properly on the page.

Comment: `<script>images = [<? foreach($tags->{$starting}->images as $id=>$image){echo $id.',';}?>];</script>` - and it's definitely creating the array, I can see it in console.log manually..

Comment: @VictorKilo ouch. just an aside, use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead to build the array.

Comment: That's a great idea.  I'm not sure why I did it with a foreach.  I am literally using json_encode the line directly above this foreach line...

Comment: unfortunately changing that did not seem to fix the problem :/

Comment: I guess I'll just implement `if(typeof(images[testingValue]) == 'undefined')` haha I just hate giving up on stuff like this...

Comment: You have a trailing comma when you recreate the array, that will cause a syntax error in IE. Other than that it should actually work.

Comment: I've since added a rtrim to get rid of it, thanks for pointing it out though :)  Chrome is just so awesome that it cleans up all the junk I put into it haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a good nights rest I was able to circle up and take a fresh look at the problem.  The variable `testingValue = 13;` is explicitly cast as an integer.  The problem was that I was getting that value dynamically through the jQuery `$.each(arrayName, function(index,value){})`.  Although the data showed that `index` was indeed an integer, for some reason `$.inArray()` was not treating it like an int/float and therefore was not finding a value in the numeric array.  I modified my code to `parseInt()` the `index` variable before checking that it was inArray.

### Long Story Short

If you are having trouble trying to use jQuery.inArray() with an array of integers or floats, try using `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`, respectively, to ensure that the function is receiving the correct data type.

```
if( jQuery.inArray(parseInt(yourVariable), yourArray) > -1)
{
    return true;
}
```